# python Selenium 'click' command only on first loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following click even within a loop that works but i only want it to be carrie out on the first loop as after that the javascipt has been activated

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='re_']/div[2]/a[1]").click()
```

any ideas how i can do this?

Comment: include that for loop in your question

Comment: Include what sorry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have some counter

```
count = 0

loop.....
    if count == 0:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='re_']/div[2]/a[1]").click()
        count = count + 1
    rest of the code
```

only the first time the loop runs, the button will be clicked